Redha OpenShift cluster- how to import the images from tar file and use the same images to create the pods

i have one tar file so using that tar file i have loaded into the vm using below command.
podman load -i ./images.tar
after that i can see the images using podman images command.
To start the container as pod it expects the images to be available in the registry but in my case images are not pushed or not available in the registry. in my cases is i don't want to push the images into the registry i want to start container as a pod by using the local images like what I have loaded in the first step.
As per my understanding if the images are available in the registry then only we can create the pods without issues mentioned in spring-boot-app . Without that if we start it is going to be an imagepullbackoff issue that is my-app.
oc get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-744b68bcc9-zhfjh      0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          20h
spring-boot-app-66bb575946-tnqgt   1/1     Running            0          20h

oc get images ---> to get the cluster images available in registry.

I need your help to start the pods without pushing my local images into the registry.

ii have one tar file so using that tar file i have loaded into the vm using below command.
podman load -i ./images.tar
after that i can see the images using podman images command.

To start the container as pod it expects the images to be available in the registry but in my case images are not pushed or not available in the registry. in my cases is i don't want to push the images into the registry i want to start container as a pod by using the local images like what I have loaded in the first step.

As per my understanding if the images are available in the registry then only we can create the pods without issues mentioned in spring-boot-app . Without that if we start it is going to be an imagepullbackoff issue that is my-app.
oc get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
my-app-744b68bcc9-zhfjh      0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0          20h
spring-boot-app-66bb575946-tnqgt   1/1     Running            0          20h


oc get images ---> to get the cluster images available in registry.

I need your help to start the pods without pushing my local images into the registry.

